# Delete all items in list from the first to the second appearance of number 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I tried to remove all items in my list L from the first to the second appearance of 0 in the list (both 0's included).

```
L = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
L[L.index(0):L.index((' '.join(L)).find('0',L.index(0)+1))] = []
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  L[L.index(0):L.index((' '.join(L)).find('0',L.index(0)+1))] = []
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

em 0: expected str instance, int found

I don't understand why and where it expected a string. Also, how can I solve this?

Comment: For a minimal example, look at what `' '.join([1, 2])` does.

Comment: `L[(s:=L.index(0)):L[s+1::].index(0)+s+2]` However it would be far more practical to just loop over the array starting at the first occurrence and stopping when you reach the next occurrence

Comment: Are there always at least 2 item "0"?

Comment: Please include the error message as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 3):

From the [zen](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) of python:

> Simple is better than complex.

```
L = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

# your L is a list where elements are of type int
```

Get the first `2 indices` of element `0` by:

```
c=0
indices=[]
for idx, x in enumerate(L):
    if x==0:
        indices.append(idx)
        c+=1
    if c==2:
        break
```

Finally, by slicing remove all the elements between 1st and 2nd occurrence of `0`:

```
L[:indices[0]+1] + L[indices[1]:]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `join` method only works for strings but you are using it on integers. You can work around this by converting it to a `str` list.

```
L[L.index(0):L.index((' '.join(list(map(str, L)))).find('0',L.index(0)+1))] = []
```

You can use the `map` function to easily convert all the `int` list to a `str` list.

```
list(map(str, L))
```

Comment: This is problematic if for example `L = [5, 0, 7, 10, 0]`. After converting to string, the code will wrongly identify the last digit of `10` as the second zero.

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic, shorter and clearer but slightly less efficient solution:

```
lst = [int(x) for x in input("Enter integers, delimited by space: ").split()]
# Enter integers, delimited by space: 1 2 3 0 4 5 0 6 7 0 8

idxs = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == 0]
new_lst = [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if (i < idxs[0] or i > idxs[1])]

print(new_lst)
# [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 0, 8]
```

It uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). It is less efficient than the solution by *Goku*, particularly for longer lists, because it has to traverse the *entire* list even though only the first 2 occurrences of 0 are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create two *[slices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)*, and concatenate them.

Here is an example.

```py
l = [ 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9 ]
l = l[:(x := l.index(0))] + l[(l.index(0, x + 1)) + 1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have converted your input into int in your list, join method doesn't work. The following is a simpler and more effective method.

```
l = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
i, c, L = 0, 0, len(l)
while i<L:
    if c==2:break
    if i == 0: c = c +1
    if c != 0: del l[i]; i = i-1; L = L-1
    i += 1


print(l)
```